# Transform json data into GeoJSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, transform, geojson

How I can get my code from this
jsonfile: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/nyc-taxi-zones

-74.18445299999996 40.694995999999904, -74.18448899999999 40.69509499999987, -74.18449799999996 40.69518499999987, -74.18438099999997 40.69587799999989, -74.18428199999994 40.6962109999999, -74.18402099999997 40.697074999999884, -74.18391299999996 40.69750699999986, -74.18375099999997 40.69779499999988, -74.18363399999998 40.6983259999999,

To this??

```
  "coordinates": [
    [-73.98597, 40.7606],
    [-73.98487, 40.76013],
    [-73.98453, 40.75999],
    [-73.9842, 40.75985],
    [-73.98400, 40.75985],
    [-73.98442, 40.75952],
    .....
```

Comment: I have a lot of this code so its not possible to correct it per hand..

Comment: Are you sure that the input you mentioned as in JSON format? or it's Java object values? If you are sure about the input and output format, better write a custom utility to convert the format.

Comment: I linked the file in the description for you